# Matlab - Plotting with for loop

Tags: matlab

I am new to matlab and am trying to loop through an equation from 1 to 1000 and plot the result, but every value is turning out the same and the plot is incrorrect.

Here is my current attempt, but the variable Rm is giving only one results (instead of 1000 separate ones):

```
Ds = 1.04e-10;
Gamma = 1.9;
Omega = 1.09e-29;
Deltas = 2.5e-10;
Boltzmann = 1.3806e-23;
T = 1123.15;
Beta = 0.83;
Zo = 6.7;
EtaNi = 0.39;
EtaYSZ = 0.61;
Rm0 = 0.29;
RmYSZ0 = 0.265;
lambda = 4.70e-3;

C = Ds * ((Gamma * Omega * Deltas) / (2 * Boltzmann * T)) * (Beta / ((1 - Beta^2) * ((1 + Beta^2)^0.5) * ((1 + Beta)^3))) * Zo * (EtaNi/((EtaNi/Rm0) + (EtaYSZ/RmYSZ0)));

tinit=1;                        % Initial time value (h)
tend=1000;                      % End time value (h)
tinc=1;                         % Increment in time value (h)
t= [tinit:tinc:tend];           % Time vector
n = 1000;
for i=1:n
     Rm(i) = (((5*C)/lambda) * (1 - exp(-lambda*i)) + (Rm0)^5)^(1/5);  
end
plot(t,Rm);
```

Expected result is an exponential curve, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Your value for `C` is extremely small at `~4e-30`. The only term in your `Rm` that changes with each iteration is scaled by `C`, resulting in a value that is many orders of magnitude smaller than the fixed value of `(Rm0)^5`. The difference in `Rm` each iteration is small enough that it can't be captured by a double precision number. I don't see any issues in the code itself, but I recommend double checking the equations and your expected results.

Comment: Check your equation. Your term `(5*C)/lambda` is equal to `4.4335e-27`, which is practically zero in numerical precision term. You multiply that by `(1 - exp(-lambda*i))` which varies between `0` and `1`, so the result will still be close to zero all the way. When you add `Rm0^5` which is `0.002051`, this dwarf the previous results and takes precedence. So your loop is simply calculating `(0.29^5)^(1/5)` all the way. That's why you get a line.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I've realised there was a problem with units which is why the value for C was incorrect. I'm now getting the result I expected!

Answer (score 0):

Your term before R0 is an exponential that ranges from 0 to 4.5e-27.  R0^5 is 0.0021.  Floating point precision is not enough to preserve the first term when it is added to the second.  So (5C/L*(...) + Rm0^5) == Rm0^5, so it is constant.